# Elasticsearch search parse exception but return a result

Tags: node.js, meteor, elasticsearch

I use ELasticsearch and Meteor.js with npm/elasticsearch plugin to use ES with Meteor.
Here is my query:

```
search = {
"body": {
  "aggs": {
    "traces": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "range": {
              "date": {
                "gte": "2015-01-31T23:00:00.000Z",
                "lte": "2015-10-02T21:59:59.000Z"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "geo_bounding_box": {
              "loc.coordinates": {
                "top_left": {
                  "lat": 51.767839887322154,
                  "lon": -9.404296875
                },
                "bottom_right": {
                  "lat": 40.96330795307353,
                  "lon": 14.326171874999998
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "or": [
              {
                "and": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "geoip": false
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "trackerId": "RG-000000010-1"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "trackerId": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "trackerId",
            "size": 0
          },
          "aggs": {
            "heatmap": {
              "geohash_grid": {
                "field": "loc.coordinates",
                "precision": 6
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

I send it with `esClient.search(search)` and receive the excepted answer but ES throws this error:

```
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:735)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:560)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:532)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:294)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:231)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:228)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:559)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [.marvel-2015.10.02]
**failed to find geo_point field [loc.coordinates]**
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.GeoBoundingBoxFilterParser.parse(GeoBoundingBoxFilterParser.java:173)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.executeFilterParser(QueryParseContext.java:368)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerFilter(QueryParseContext.java:349)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.AndFilterParser.parse(AndFilterParser.java:65)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.executeFilterParser(QueryParseContext.java:368)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerFilter(QueryParseContext.java:349)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parseInnerFilter(IndexQueryParserService.java:295)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.filter.FilterParser.parse(FilterParser.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorParsers.parseAggregators(AggregatorParsers.java:148)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorParsers.parseAggregators(AggregatorParsers.java:78)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregationParseElement.parse(AggregationParseElement.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:719)
```

Apparently it does not find the geo_point field type.

Here is the revelant part of my mapping:

```
{
            'trace': {
                'properties': {
                    'loc': {
                        'type': 'object',
                        'properties': {
                            'type': {
                                'type': 'string'
                            },
                            'coordinates':{
                                'type': 'geo_point',
                                'geohash':true,
                                'geohash_prefix':true,
                                'lat_lon':true,
                                'fielddata' : {
                                    'format' : 'compressed',
                                    'precision' : '1cm'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
    ...
```

So why the geo_point type is not found ?

Comment: Can you show the URL you're sending the query to?

Comment: It is not an URL. I use NPM Elasticsearch, a ES api wrapper for node.js So it is simply `esClient.search(search)`

Comment: can you show what settings you have in the `search` options hash?

Comment: You mean the content of the search var? In this case it is the first part of my question. I will edit it to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send your query to the index that contains the documents of type `trace`. If you send the query to the root endpoint `/` (default if not specified) then all indices will be queried. In your case, it fails because the `.marvel-2015.10.02` index doesn't have any `geo_point` field named `loc.coordinates`.

So your call needs to look like this:

```
var search = {
    index: "your_index",             <--- add this
    body: {...}
};
esClient.search(search);
```

Comment: ho. Perfect. Thanks Val :)